# Work out years : months : days left

Tags: jquery

trying to work out the time left between 2 dates

I think I am close, but I get faulty results for my days and years, I have checked other solutions but they are different to the way I am trying to do it... can I do what I need with the way I am doing it?

```
var seconds= Math.floor((timeLeft/1000)%60);
var minutes= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60))%60);
var hours= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60*60))%24);
var dayz= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60*60*24))%31);
var years= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60*60*24*31))%12);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var currentDate = new Date(2017, 08, 07 , 14 , 33, 20); //set fixed dates to test with
var futureDate = new Date(2018, 08, 07 , 14 , 33, 20); //set fixed dates to test with

var countDown = setInterval(function() {
  
  
   var currentD = new Date(2017, 08, 07 , 14 , 33, 20); //set fixed dates to test with
   var timeLeft = new Date();
   timeLeft = futureDate - currentD;
  
            var seconds= Math.floor((timeLeft/1000)%60);
   var minutes= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60))%60);
   var hours= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60*60))%24);
   var dayz= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60*60*24))%31);
            var years= Math.floor((timeLeft/(1000*60*60*24*31))%12);
  
  
      $('#timeLeft').text(years + " " + dayz + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds);

  
  
}, 1000);


  $('#currentDate').text( currentDate);
  $('#futureDate').text(futureDate);  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Current Date: <span id="currentDate"></span><br/>
Future Date: <span id="futureDate"></span><br/>
Time till: <span id="timeLeft"></span><br/>
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that you're assuming that the average days per month are 31 when instead are 30.41.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using momentjs instead. It would make things very simple... Below will give you the difference in days, but you can easily have every possible format for your difference:

```js
var currentDate = moment([2017, 8, 7 , 14 , 33, 20]); //set fixed dates to test with
var futureDate = moment([2018, 8, 7 , 14 , 33, 20]);
var format = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";
document.getElementById("currentDate").appendChild(document.createTextNode(currentDate.format(format)));
document.getElementById("futureDate").appendChild(document.createTextNode(futureDate.format(format)));

var difference = futureDate.diff(currentDate, 'days', true);
var durationReadable = moment.duration(futureDate.diff(currentDate)).humanize(true);

document.getElementById("timeLeft").appendChild(document.createTextNode(difference));
document.getElementById("duration").appendChild(document.createTextNode(durationReadable));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

Current Date: <span id="currentDate"></span><br/>
Future Date: <span id="futureDate"></span><br/>
Time till: <span id="timeLeft"></span><br/>
Time till humanized: <span id="duration"></span>
```

Comment: Very nice script, but I am doing this to learn, so I need to learn the hard way and figure out how to build it myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got it,
Here is the solution for anyone who is a noob like me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var showOne = new Date();
var showTwo = new Date(2016, 08, 14);
$('#showOne').text( showOne);  
$('#showTwo').text( showTwo );


setInterval(function(){
var currentDateSec = $.now() / 1000 ;
var laterDate = showTwo;
var laterDateSec = laterDate / 1000;
var timeLeft = laterDateSec - currentDateSec;

var sLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft) %60;
var mLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft/(60)) %60;
var hLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft/(60 * 60)) %24;
var dLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft/(60 * 60 * 24)) %7;
var wLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft/(60 * 60 * 24 * 7));


  $('#currentDate').text( currentDateSec);  
  $('#futureDate').text(laterDateSec);
  $('#timeLeft').text(timeLeft);
  
  $('#sLeft').text(sLeft);
  $('#mLeft').text(mLeft);
  $('#hLeft').text(hLeft);
  $('#dLeft').text(dLeft);
  $('#wLeft').text(wLeft);
  
$('#humandate').text(wLeft + " Weeks - " + dLeft + " Days - " + hLeft + " Hours - " + mLeft + " Mins - " + sLeft + " Sec\(s\)");
  
  
}, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="showOne"></span><br/>
<span id="showTwo"></span><br/>
<br/><br/>
Current Date: <span id="currentDate"></span><br/>
Future Date: <span id="futureDate"></span><br/>
Seconds till: <span id="sLeft"></span><br/>
Mins till: <span id="mLeft"></span><br/>
Hours till: <span id="hLeft"></span><br/>
Days till: <span id="dLeft"></span><br/>
Weeks till: <span id="wLeft"></span><br/>
<br/><br/>
<span id="humandate"></span><br/>
```